# Detect an a priori unknown pattern in dataset

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Are there any algorithms/tools to detect an a priori unknown pattern in input sequence of discrete symbols?

For example, for string "01001000100001" it is something like ("0"^i"1")*,
and for "01001100011100001111" it is like ("0"^i"1"^i)*

I've found some approaches but they are applied when a set of patterns to detect in a sequence is a priori known. I've also found the [sequitur algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequitur_algorithm) for hierarchical structure detection in data but it does not work when the sequence is like "arithmetic progression" like in my examples.

So I'll be very thankful for any information about method/algorithm/tool/scientific paper.

Comment: Try looking at algorithms used for branch prediction, they might help.

Comment: Is it required to detect "nonlinear" patterns like `"0"^(i^2)"1"` such as in sequence `01000010000000001...`?

Comment: Yes, "nonlinear" have to be recognized

Comment: Pretty sure the general case of 'any pattern' cannot be solved, it sounds too much like [Kolmogorov Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). Is the pattern you are looking for only a regex? It might simplify things. (No idea if it does)

Comment: The  case of 'any pattern' is the best but because of its complexity I hope to find a certain method detecting patterns from particular set (as wide as possible). So any set meets me but the more the better

Comment: What if the sequence is the binary representation of pi, with leading zeros omitted? That is a pretty strong pattern, but obviously it will never be complete...

Comment: Its clear many patterns can't be detected actually, but I'm trying to find at least one method/tool to detect certain class of patterns

Comment: Is the program creating the strings deterministic or stochastic?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that as someone pointed out, the general case is not solvable. Douglas Hofstadter spent a lot of time studying this problem, and describes some approaches (some automated, some manual), see the first chapter of:

[http://www.amazon.com/Fluid-Concepts-And-Creative-Analogies/dp/0465024750](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465024750)

I believe his general approach was to do use an AI search algorithm (depth or breadth first search combined with some good heuristics). Using the algorithm would generate possible sequences using different operators (such as repeat the previous digit i times, or i/2 times) and follow branches in the search tree where the operations specified by the nodes along that branch had correctly predicted the next digit(s), until it can successfully predict the sequence far enough ahead that you are satisfied that it has the correct answer. It would then output the sequence of operations that constitute the pattern (although these operations need to be designed by the user as building blocks for the pattern generation).

Also, genetic programming may be able to solve this problem.